# How to test cloudwatch alarm locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am using AWS CDK library to create alarm and metric. Both component have been created fine and once deploy cloudformation template using cdk deploy command then components are visible in AWS env.
But sometime things are not executed as per exceptions therefor need to test locally.

Is there any way to test CloudWatch alarm locally ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write a test where you set the alarm state in a language supported by AWS SDK. i.e Python below

```py
response = client.set_alarm_state(
  AlarmName='string',
  StateValue='OK'|'ALARM'|'INSUFFICIENT_DATA',
  StateReason='string',
  StateReasonData='string'
)
```

or AWS CLI

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "{YOUR_ALARM}" --state-reason "Testing alarm" --state-value ALARM
```